# Send two JSON via same HTTP message

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, d3.js

I have a Nodejs and d3.js programs which handle json data, send it via cross-domain and save a file. I have two JSON array which are: **nodes** and **links**. I need to save these into a file in another domain. In front-end side I am preparing http message like this,

```
function sendLinks()
{
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'http://192.168.80.143:2800/',
            data:JSON.stringify(links),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            error: function(data)
            {
                console.log("error", data);
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log("success", data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

In the server side, I have the following code(nodejs)

```
    app.use(function(req, res) {
    //write a file
    fs.writeFile('links.json', JSON.stringify(req.body), function(err) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('File created > links.json');    
    });

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.write('Message taken: \n');
    res.end(req.body);
    res.send("OK");

});
```

I want to do that for **nodes** JSON array in a different file name(e.g. nodes.json). How can I do that? Can I handle with the same http message?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return `data: JSON.stringify({ links: links, nodes: nodes })`, and unpack appropriately at serverside.